# How to group similar data in a column using nlp in r?

Tags: r, machine-learning, nlp, data-analysis

complete dataset link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=12u0Ql1z5T2lzCXRVjp75i9ke9mNYrCWv

In this you can see general motors are not counted together as they are in different category. Like this many more manufacturer's are there. I want to group them together like General Motors. How can I group them together using `nlp` in `r`?

Comment: Could you please provide your sample data via `dput` this would make it easier to read it in. In any case you can simply remove the unwanted trailing patterns (you probably know them in advance) via `gsub("pattern1|pattern2|...", "", x)`.

Comment: complete dataset link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=12u0Ql1z5T2lzCXRVjp75i9ke9mNYrCWv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way to achieve your goal:

Your Input data.frame:

```
Vehicle_Manufacturer<-c("GENERAL MOTORS CORP.","FORD MOTOR COMPANY","CHRYSLER CORPORATION","PACCAR INCORPORATED","MACK TRUCKS, INCORPORATED","FOREST RIVER, INC.","BLUE BIRD BODY COMPANY","DAIMLER TRUCKS NORTH AMERICA","GENERAL MOTORS LLC","HONEYWELL INTERNATIONAL, INC.","WINNEBAGO INDUSTRIES, INC.","BMW OF NORTH AMERICA, LLC","NISSAN NORTH AMERICA, INC.","NAVISTAR INTL CORP.","INTERNATIONAL TRUCK AND ENGINE","FREIGHTLINER LLC","HONDA (AMERICAN HONDA MOTOR CO.)","NEWMAR CORPORATION","NAVISTAR, INC","INTERNATIONAL TRUCK & ENGINE CORPORATION","PIERCE MANUFACTURING","GULF STREAM COACH, INC.","FLEETWOOD ENTERPRISES, INC.","FREIGHTLINER CORPORATION","DAIMLER TRUCKS NORTH AMERICA LLC","PACCAR, INCORPORATED","WHITE MOTOR CORPORATION","BAYERISCHE MOTOREN WERKE","THOMAS BUILT BUSES, INC.","DAIMLERCHRYSLER CORPORATION","VOLKSWAGEN OF AMERICA,INC","SPARTAN MOTORS, INC.","VOLVO TRUCKS NORTH AMERICA INC","TOYOTA MOTOR ENGINEERING & MANUFACTURING","PREVOST CAR, INCORPORATED","CHAMPION BUS, INC.","ALTEC INDUSTRIES INC.","SABERSPORT","MERCEDES-BENZ USA, LLC.","HARLEY-DAVIDSON MOTOR COMPANY","COOPER TIRE & RUBBER CO.","KEYSTONE RV COMPANY","SUBARU OF AMERICA, INC.","CHRYSLER (FCA US LLC)","MONACO COACH CORPORATION","CHRYSLER GROUP LLC","JAYCO, INC.","MITSUBISHI FUSO TRUCK OF AMERICA, INC.","COLLINS BUS CORPORATION","PRO-A MOTORS, INC.","NAVISTAR, INC.")
Recalls<-c(6228,5403,2787,2317,1988,1903,1898,1737,1620,1558,1353,1297,1174,1130,1055,987,985,980,955,950,925,922,918,896,835,824,818,801,797,794,749,731,724,709,694,669,641,623,616,613,599,586,582,578,578,572,569,568,559,549,511)
df<-data.frame(Vehicle_Manufacturer,Recalls)
```

Using package `stringdist` find similar strings between `Vehicle_Manufacturer`, in this example using Jaro-Winkler distance:

```
dist_matrix<-stringdistmatrix(as.character(df[,1]),as.character(df[,1]),method="jw")
```

Find a threshold under that similar strings are grouped, like this:

```
thr<-quantile(dist_matrix,probs=0.025) #2.5% quantile
```

Find strings to merge (in this example a for-loop but if you have a lot of data a `lapply` solution is better)

```
to_merge<-NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  to_merge[[i]]<-Vehicle_Manufacturer[dist_matrix[i,]<thr]
}
```

Your output will be in `to_merge` list

To see only possible merge:

```
to_merge[sapply(to_merge, length) > 1]
[[1]]
[1] "GENERAL MOTORS CORP." "GENERAL MOTORS LLC"  

[[2]]
[1] "PACCAR INCORPORATED"  "PACCAR, INCORPORATED"

[[3]]
[1] "MACK TRUCKS, INCORPORATED" "PACCAR, INCORPORATED"     

[[4]]
[1] "DAIMLER TRUCKS NORTH AMERICA"     "DAIMLER TRUCKS NORTH AMERICA LLC"

[[5]]
[1] "GENERAL MOTORS CORP." "GENERAL MOTORS LLC"  

[[6]]
[1] "NAVISTAR INTL CORP." "NAVISTAR, INC"       "NAVISTAR, INC."     

[[7]]
[1] "NAVISTAR INTL CORP." "NAVISTAR, INC"       "NAVISTAR, INC."     

[[8]]
[1] "DAIMLER TRUCKS NORTH AMERICA"     "DAIMLER TRUCKS NORTH AMERICA LLC"

[[9]]
[1] "PACCAR INCORPORATED"       "MACK TRUCKS, INCORPORATED" "PACCAR, INCORPORATED"     

[[10]]
[1] "NAVISTAR INTL CORP." "NAVISTAR, INC"       "NAVISTAR, INC."
```

Comment: Nice solution. For speeding up the human validation step, you might limit the check on list items with more than one entry, which can be found, e.g., via `sapply(to_merge, length) > 1`.

Comment: Good idea @ManuelBickel, I have integrated your suggestion in the answer

Comment: Is it possible to take only first 2 words from every column? I am asking this because most of the data are merging with the last word and the first name is changing automatically.

Comment: I don't think is a good idea, in the last couple of elements [[10]] you have the same Manufacturer but considering only first 2 words they are different: "NAVISTAR INTL" vS "NAVISTAR INC".

Comment: In small dataset it's working fine. But when I am integrating it with my full dataset it's not giving perfect result. Can you check with the link of my dataset? At the last of the dataset itself we can see the difference.

Comment: You will never have an automatic perfect result. If you have a lot of false positive use a more coercive threshold like this: thr<-quantile(dist_matrix,probs=0.0005). I tried it on your dataset and the result is pretty good.